# Rails app: css not working as expected

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I try to stylify my html in a basic Rails app. The app loads the home.scss file but my styling of the header does not work. It appears only the new font family works. Any idea about this issue?

My application.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Content Style</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <h1 id="logo">ContentStyle.co</h1>
      <% if notice %>
        <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>
      <% end %>
      <% if alert %>
        <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
      <% end %>
      <ul>
        <%= render 'devise/menu/registration_items' %>
        <%= render 'devise/menu/login_items' %>
      </ul>
    </header>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= yield :save_js %>
  </body>
</html>
```

My home.scss file

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crete+Round');

body {
  font-family: 'Crete Round', serif;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 20px 150px 20px 150px;
  background-color: #2C64C1;
}

#logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

The header background-color should be blue but here is how it looks (the h1 text is in white as expected so we don't see it):
[image]

Comment: Have you tried any troubleshooting measures like checking the console or the rails log? The code in the question looks perfectly fine. The one thing I can see is that your handling of flash messages looks a bit wonky and unconventional - usually you just iterate through the flash hash.

Comment: What should I check in the console? Here is the log which seems fine: Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2017-01-31 15:37:11 +0100
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
  Rendered devise/menu/_registration_items.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered devise/menu/_login_items.html.erb (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 39ms (Views: 35.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: The weird thing is that only my header { ... } css is not taken into account...

Comment: I just changed the position of the header { ... } and now it works... Mystery!

Comment: Could be something like a non breaking space character which the browser chokes on.

Comment: Yes, it was probably the problem!